# How to select either one row or the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns VAT, start and end date.
I have two rows. The standard entry has `0000-00-00` as the start and end date and the other row has the start_date `2020-06-01` and the end_date `2020-12-31`

I want VAT of the second row to be selected if today's date is between the start and end date, otherwise the standard VAT with `0000-00-00` should be selected

This is my table:

[image]

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM taxes
WHERE (CASE WHEN start_date < "2020-06-06"
                AND end_date > "2020-06-06" THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END) = 1
```

But i don't know how to formulate the else case or whether it can work at all like this

Comment: Sorry i edited my Post. I hope my problem is clearer now.

Comment: Added the `mysql` tag because no other DBMS allows invalid dates like `0000-00-00`

Comment: I just tested in MySql version "5.7.12-log" and the date `'0000-00-00'` wasn't allowed there either ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit` for this:

```
select t.*
from taxes t
where start_date = '0000-00-00' or
      '2020-06-06' between start_date and end_date
order by start_date desc
limit 1;
```

The idea is that the first condition gets the "default" value.  The second condition gets the matching condition.  These two rows are then sorted, so the matching condition will be first -- if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

There might be ways o doing it with your suggested "0000-00-00' dates for start and end points, but in my view you run a much cleaner ship if you address the time spans individually, i. e. spell out the date ranges for before and after the "exception period", like:

```
INSERT INTO vat (startdt,enddt,fullrate,reducedrate) 
       VALUES ('2000-01-01','2020-06-30',.19,.07), -- before
              ('2020-07-01','2020-12-31',.16,.05), -- exception period
              ('2021-01-01','2500-12-31',.19,.07); -- after

select * from vat where now() between startdt and enddt;
```

This way you document in a very clear way which rates were applicable when. And the query itself becomes trivial, see above and check out my demo here: https://rextester.com/YLYUU53617

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM taxes 
WHERE tax_id=IF(start_date < "2020-06-06" AND end_date > "2020-06-06", 1, 0)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL, I agree.  But in this case, the solution is so simple that I think it's intuitively obvious as to how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the records for current date, then combine this set with the source table filtered by '0000-00-00' excluding country codes from this set

```
with 
 current_taxes as (
    select *
    from taxes 
    where current_date between start_date and end_date 
)
select *
from current_taxes
union all 
select *
from taxes 
left join current_taxes
using (country_code)
where taxes.start_date='0000-00-00'
and current_taxes.country_code is null
;
```